# What is the difference between mvn pre-clean / clean / post-clean?

Tags: maven, mvn-repo, maven-lifecycle, maven-clean-plugin

what is the difference between these 3 commands: mvn pre-clean / clean / post-clean? Pre and post are unusual to be used. We go straight forward with mvn clean but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default lifecycle bindings, `pre-clean` and `post-clean` are empty phases. So calling `pre-clean` will do nothing and calling `post-clean` will be the same as `clean`.

You could, of course, bind goals to theses phases and then use them.